# How to apply digital signature to my code

Tags: java, angularjs, digital-signature

Is it possible to apply a digital signature to my code or to the whole project?

I need to protect my Java code and my Angular code to prevent anyone from possibly tampering with or editing it. I would that no one could modify It.

Searching on internet I can't find any solution except to use MD5 but I don't understand It very well.. so can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain how applying a digital signature would prevent someone from editing it? What is the context?

Comment: Your Java code is protected, being deployed on the server.  Your Angular code is not, and there is no way to protect any client-side code.  The base assumption needs to be that the client is untrusted and so all sensitive actions need to be done on the server side.  The client is only responsible for tracking the session id (a randomly generated variable with an expiry) + issue commands.

Comment: One possible route is to obfuscate[link](https://dev.to/hmintoh/react-obfuscate-hiding-source-code-from-developer-tools-4ci6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For backend - you can [sign the code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) assuming you have a keypair..

> I would that no one could modify It.

The purpose of the signing is ensure that no one changed the code. That's more assurance for the client of the origin and integrity of the code.

If you are runnig the code on a server under your control, you have to worry less, but you may still get the assurance.

If you want to make sure no-one changed the code on the runnig on the client side, your options are limited. Someone changing part of the code may as well change the code checking for integrity (see how much money and time are game companies spending on DRM and how long it lasts)

For the client side (JS), you may check https://blog.bitsrc.io/the-importance-of-integrity-checks-in-javascript-c6fde630e7   but as well, it's assurance for the client, not for the service provider